# How can I extract Twitter @handles from a text with RegEx?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for an easy way to create lists of Twitter @handles based on SocialBakers data (copy/paste into TextMate).

I've tried using the following RegEx, which I found here on StackOverflow, but unfortunately it doesn't work the way I want it to:

```
^(?!.*@([\w+])).*$
```

While the expression above deletes all lines without @handles, I'd like the RegEx to delete everything before and after the @handle as well as lines without @handles.

Example:

```
1
katyperry KATY PERRY (@katyperry)
Followings 158
Followers 82 085 596
Rating
5
Worst012345678910Best
2
justinbieber Justin Bieber (@justinbieber)
254 399
74 748 878
2
Worst012345678910Best
3
taylorswift13 Taylor Swift (@taylorswift13)
245
70 529 992
```

Desired result:

```
@katyperry
@justinbieber
@taylorswift13
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So you wish to extract only handles ?

Comment: A simple regex like `/@[a-z0-9_]+/g` will do the job. [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dC9zS1/1). BTW what flavor are you using ?

Comment: Why are you trying to delete all other text rather than match only the text you need? It'd be like calling in all your employees for a meeting and then telling 95% of them to leave again. Regex is not made for negating, and simply matching twitter handles would be a lot better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
cat file | perl -ne 'while(s/(@[a-z0-9_]+)//gi) { print $1,"\n"}'
```

This will also work if you have lines with multiple @handles in.

Answer (score 0):

A Twitter handle regex is `@\w+`. So, to remove everything else, you need to match and capture the pattern and use a backreference to this capture group, and then just match any character:

```
(@\w+)|.
```

Use DOTALL mode to also match newline symbols. Replace with `$1` (or `\1`, depending on the tool you are using).

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC9iL4/1)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful!

Comment: `@\w+` will falsely match with email addresses.

Comment: @Merchako What an old answer. If you care to avoid emails, use `\B(@\w+)|.`

Answer (score 0):

## Strait REGEX Tested in Caret:

```
@.*[^)]
```

The above will search for and any given and exclude close parenthesis.

```
@.*\b
```

The above here does the same thing in Caret text editor.

## How to awk and sed this:

Get usernames as well:

```
$ awk '/@.*/ {print}' test
katyperry KATY PERRY (@katyperry)
justinbieber Justin Bieber (@justinbieber)
taylorswift13 Taylor Swift (@taylorswift13)
```

Just the Handle:

```
$ awk -F "(" '/@.*/ {print$2}' test | sed 's/)//g'
@katyperry
@justinbieber
@taylorswift13
```

A look at the test file:

```
$ cat test
1
katyperry KATY PERRY (@katyperry)
Followings 158
Followers 82 085 596
Rating
5
Worst012345678910Best
2
justinbieber Justin Bieber (@justinbieber)
254 399
74 748 878
2
Worst012345678910Best
3
taylorswift13 Taylor Swift (@taylorswift13)
245
70 529 992
```

Bash Version:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```